# Combination Of Two Strings With Incremented Value In jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to Increment the Letters and i Need to match the letters with combinations.

```
var allArrays = new Array(['a','c'],['b','e'],['r','s']);

function getPermutation(array, prefix) {
    prefix = prefix || '';
    if (!array.length) {
        return prefix;
    }

    var result = array[0].reduce(function (result, value) {
        return result.concat(getPermutation(array.slice(1), prefix + value));
    }, []);
    return result;
}

console.log(getPermutation(allArrays));
```

where ['a','c']

a, b, r  ---> From Location

c, e, s  ---> To Location

same follows for remaining arrays.

I need to get the output as

```
"abr","abs","acr","acs","adr","ads","aer","aes","bbr","bbs","bcr","bcs","bdr","bds","ber","bes","cbr","cbs","ccr","ccs","cdr","cds","cer","ces"
```

But I'm Getting the output as like this,

```
"abr","abs","aer","aes","cbr","cbs","cer","ces"
```

I'm Getting Only Combinations Between them , But i'm trying to Increment upto the letters given and has to do combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fill the gaps first and then apply `getPermutation`.

```js
function getPermutation(array, prefix) {
    prefix = prefix || '';
    if (!array.length) {
        return prefix;
    }

    var result = array[0].reduce(function (result, value) {
        return result.concat(getPermutation(array.slice(1), prefix + value));
    }, []);
    return result;
}

var allArrays = new Array(['a', 'c'], ['b', 'e'], ['r', 's']);

allArrays.forEach(function (a) {
    var value = parseInt(a[0], 36) + 1,
        last = a.pop(),
        lastValue = parseInt(last, 36);
  
    while (value <= lastValue) {
        a.push(value.toString(36));
        value++;
    }
});

console.log(allArrays);
console.log(getPermutation(allArrays));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A solution for letters and any numbers, despite the order, with a check for type and using a variable for incrementing/decrementing the value.

```js
function getPermutation(array, prefix) {
    prefix = prefix || '';
    if (!array.length) {
        return prefix;
    }

    return array[0].reduce(function (result, value) {
        return result.concat(getPermutation(array.slice(1), prefix + value));
    }, []);
}

var allArrays = new Array(['a', 'c'], ['e', 'b'], ['02', '04'], ['32', '29']);

allArrays.forEach(function (a) {
    var length = a[1].length,
        pad = isNaN(a[0]) ? ' ' : '0',
        radix = isNaN(a[0]) ? 36 : 10,
        value = parseInt(a[0], radix),
        lastValue = parseInt(a.pop(), radix),
        inc = +(lastValue >= value) || -1,
        temp;

    value += inc;
    while (inc === 1 ? value <= lastValue : value >= lastValue) {
        temp = value.toString(radix);
        while (temp.length < length) {
            temp = pad + temp;
        }
        a.push(temp);
        value += inc;
    }
});

console.log(allArrays);
console.log(getPermutation(allArrays));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanq @nina Scholz

Comment: Hi @nina Scholz, If i Give Number in place of ` ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'e']`   as         ['2', '3'], ['5', '2'] then it will work?

Comment: no, actually this works only for letters. if you change the requirement, you need to change the interpretation of the values.

Comment: Hi Nina,  actually this works only for letters right, i need to work with numbers. can you help me on this thing how to move?

Comment: Yes its working, but zero's are missing, like ['01', '05'], ['01', '10'], ['01', '02'] the problem is its skipping zero's. example: 010101 is the required output i'm getting like 111.@Nina

Comment: No, actually it may be like only alphabets or only numbers both does not exist in one scenario.

Comment: you can see this one, my problem is Zero's are excluding from 01 to 1 in the middle of the array. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lz6hzj2/).

Comment: I'm thinking to add zero's after increment like this,                                   function addzeros(number, length) {
    var num = '' + number;
    while (num.length < length) {
        num = '0' + num;
    }
    return num;
}

Comment: @RaviKumar, right, a while loop helps in this case.

Comment: Thanks @nina, I got the result.

Comment: I have tried in different way but your solution is more accurate than me.